# iOS Provisioning profile expiring after 6 days

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

I'm new to iOS development as i currently develop only for android.
I run into a problem and i have been searching a lot for a possible solution.
I would like to make a personal iOS app (something like a personal note app or a personal reminder app etc) and well i made it . The only problem was that the provisioning profile lasts only 6 days (i think) and the app stops working as i need to repair the Provisioning profile. 
Now as this app is personal (no need to distribuite anywhere and i don't have a paid developer account ) is there a possible way to install it forever into my iPhone without expiration as i can't use my company development profile for signin it. any type of help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance and have a nice day !

Comment: Since Xcode 7 free provisioning profiles are limited in life time for a week...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible to have an app installed 'forever' on your device if it's not installed via the App Store, it will need 're-provisioning' occasionally in order to still be valid.

The reason your app expires after 6 days is that this is the time limit on applications deployed to devices using Apple's free developer program. There are also a few other limitations relating to capabilities enabled via entitlements.

The paid developer program increases this time limit to 1 year. Other distribution methods (such as Enterprise distribution) also have similar time limits.

Comment: ahh, thats why i have been searching a lot with no result, thankyou anyways @WDUk

Comment: @WDUK Can you write more about 're-provisioning'? When I have provisioning profile and it is not valid, then do I need to reconnect an iPhone, clean and rebuild project to perform re-provisioning? Or something else is needed? I'd like to keep the same app bundle identifier.