# Unity3D on iOS - Vuforia always stops working after a few days

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm using Unity3D and Vuforia for a long time without any issues. Since the latest iOS update (12.x) I got some problems. The AR apps have been working fine for a few days (5-7) and then suddenly stop working - app opens and close immediately. After re-compiling, the same story, it last for few days only...Anyone any idea or similar problems?

Unity 2018.1
iOS 12.1
Vuforia: free/test license
Xcode 9.2 (my workaround with the extracted packages from Xcode 10 [iOS 12 not supported by Xcode 9.4 : Could not locate device support files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51215836/ios-12-not-supported-by-xcode-9-4-could-not-locate-device-support-files) , as I can't upgrade my OSX at the moment)

Answer (score 0):

Sound like free provisioning profiles issue.

If you are using Apple's free developer program, free provisioning profiles are limited in life time for a week.

Ref:
[iOS Provisioning profile expiring after 6 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46284022/ios-provisioning-profile-expiring-after-6-days)

Answer (score 0):

OMG - of course!!! I've checked Xcode and the profile was set to **personal** after I forgot to renew the license.

All good now, Thanks :)